# How to change full text index minimum word length with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xampp, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I'm using windows operating system and xampp control panel. I want to change full text index minimum word length. Most of post explain it can be changed through mysql my.ini file. But my mysql my.ini file doesn't show any thing as "ft_min_word_len". How can I change it? Is there any other place that is exist?

Comment: Add the setting to the init file. If it's not in there, it uses the default.

Comment: @Barmar How can I add it? Is there any other place that min_word_length exist?

Comment: You add it with a text editor, just like any other server option.

Answer (score 2):

Open this file:

Windows:

```
C:\\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf
```

Linux:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

---

Add this: (if it does not exist in that file)

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 3 // or any number you like
```

Restart MySQL... Done.

Also you can see it in here:

[image]